# NoSuchMethodException/SAXParseException while deploying application on Tomcat

Tags: java, hibernate, primefaces, jersey

My project is using Java, Jersey, MyfacesCODI, primefaces, Hibernate.
In this environment when I am deploying my project in Tomcat, it is getting an error saying

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: 
    org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml addResourceEnvRef
```

and

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; 
systemId: jndi:/localhost/School/WEB-INF/web.xml;
lineNumber: 13;
columnNumber: 22;
Error at (13, 22) :
   org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml addResourceEnvRef
```

What may be the issue? Any environment related issues?
Thanks

Comment: @userXYZ and the /WEB-INF/web.xml file data from around line 13
... siebz0r sorry my bad for some reason I thought SO provided 50 token rep

Answer (score 0):

normally you can simply add

`<WatchedResource>your project/target/classes</WatchedResource>`

to your tomcat server context.xml file to solve this problem. however it will not always work for some reason. So another solution here:

then  add `<Loader delegate="true" />` to your tomcat server context.xml can probably solve this problem too.